# ASP.NET LocalResources same filename

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have a small question and I think this is asked before but I can't seem to find it...

I have 2 pages:

> /Default.aspx
>
> /Profile/Default.aspx

The resource file for the `/Default.aspx` is in `/App_LocalResources/Default.aspx.resx` but where do I place the `Default.aspx.resx` for the `/Profile/Default.aspx`?

When I place it in `/App_LocalResources/Profile/Default.aspx.resx` it keeps telling me the resource isn't found...

I access the resources like this: `<%$ Resources:lblHeader.Text %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try
    /Profile/App_LocalResources/Default.aspx.resx

Comment: Thanks! That makes more sense :-)